# how to save page source using urllib3 in Python

Tags: python

I know how to save page source code using urllib2

```
import urllib2
page = urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com')
page_source = page.read()
with open('page_source.html', 'w') as fid:
fid.write(page_source)
```

But how to save a source using urllib3? PoolManager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **.data**, like this:

```
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('get', 'http://www.google.com')

with open('page_source.html', 'w') as fid:
    fid.write(r.data)
```